# What is the difference between "domain" and "register"?

Tags: terminology

It seems like "domain" is a broad categorization of context (e.g. workplace, academia) and register is the specific set of rules which are expected by those speaking in a certain domain. Is this right?

Comment: In what context did you encounter the two terms? Their meaning is very much dependent on that.

Comment: "[Register](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_(sociolinguistics))" is a common sociolinguistics term. I'm not sure I've heard "domain" being used as a technical linguistic term with the sense you indicate. "[Semantic domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_domain)" is common but has a rather different usage.

Answer (score 1):

Your use of 'domain' and 'register' is meaningful, but:

Communication choices are made to fit a **diatype**, which consists of *field*, *tenor*, and *mode*.  Your 'domain' corresponds to the 'field' (situational context), and your 'register' corresponds to the 'tenor' (style based on roles).  The 'mode' is the communication channel (speech, writing, etc.)

'Register' can refer to either the entire diatype, or just the tenor.  *Tenor* can be called *style* instead.  It once equated to the level of formality (inverse of intimacy), but has been expanded to include other emotional motives such as humor or derision.